# How to make Dropbox auto start on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE?

Tags: 16.04, mate, dropbox, autostart, ubuntu-mate

I have installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.4 LTS. Then I did the following to install Dropbox:

1. I installed `caja-dropbox` package to it.

   During installation of `caja-dropbox` proprietary part was downloaded (DropBox v.43.4.50), then it opened Firefox for authentication, after it opened Caja in `~/Dropbox` folder. Also it shown icon in notification area/tray.
2. I clicked on systemtray icon, selected *Preferences->General* and checked *Start Dropbox on system start-up* and rebooted.
3. After reboot I do not have Dropbox icon in tray, it does not have desktop-file in XDG autostart (`~/.config/autostart`).

What should I do to make Dropbox autostart with system on MATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having 15-minutes of googling I found solution (see [launchpad bug 1604439](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/caja-dropbox/+bug/1604439)).

The solution:

```
caja-dropbox autostart y
```

After reboot Dropbox shows its icon in system-tray, Caja shows overlay icon on `~/Dropbox` folder and works correctly.

Note: this solution works on coming Ubuntu 18.04 LTS too.